# Programmatically initiate html5 datetime-local

Tags: html, datetime

is there anyway to initiate the calendar / time view from the html5 element type="datetime-local" ?

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="dtl" />

<script>
$('#dtl').click();
</script>
```

doesn't work, even though you can listen for events on click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, not really.

The HTML5 calendar view is implemented differently by each browser, so there's no solid way of activating the browser's datetime calendar picker. The best you could do is probably `$('#dtl').focus();` to focus in the field, but I know that's not what you want.

A cross-browser alternative is to use something like the [jQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Comment: That's what I thought.  I wanted to have a span that had a 'pretty' version of the date that when clicked could show the calender. Oh well.

Comment: Look into the jQuery UI datepicker. If you're already using jQuery, it's not hard to implement. Plus, it's a cross-browser solution and you can make it look however you want.

Comment: That's a good idea.  I am actually building a web app using webshims and wanted to default to datetime-local if available, but for now it looks like i'll opt for the jQuery solution.

Comment: In case you are already using webshims you can simply set webshims.setOptions('forms-ext', {replaceUI: true}); and have a datepicker, which can be customized (much better one than jQuery UI).

Answer (score 1):

2023 update: Yes you can!

You can open it using [HTMLInputElement.showPicker()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/showPicker)

```
document.querySelector('#dtl').showPicker()
```

Comment: I confirm that this function works as expected